# How to change a column name and display with special characters?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to display one column name with '%' i.e the "ip_utilization" column as "usage%" column here. But i am not able to, can anyone suggest a solution please. I am sharing the query.

```
select ip_name, concat (first_name, ' ' ,last_name) as Contact, ip_utilization as usage_% from database_name;
```

Comment: Don't do this. Just... don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enclose usage_% in `` as below:

```
select ip_name, concat (first_name, ' ' ,last_name) as Contact, ip_utilization as `usage_%` from database_name;
```

If you have further problems, leave a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Just give it a different column name? Like `usage_percentage`.

It may be possible to have the percent sign using backticks, but to what end? What point is there in jumping through hoops to somehow have a weird special character in a name that usually won't be displayed in an application anyway?*

<sub>(Unless it's really a public-facing app and you can't change the name on application level at all. But that should be the rare exception.)</sub>

Comment: I did that only but the requirement is not mine and it needs '%'... Hope u understand :)

Comment: @user but *why*? Will the name be public facing?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use backticks

```
select ip_name, concat (first_name, ' ' ,last_name) as Contact, ip_utilization as `usage_%` from database_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Quote usage%. But I advice to change the name, because % is keyword used for like command.

```
select ip_name, concat (first_name, ' ' ,last_name) as Contact,
ip_utilization as 'usage_%' from database_name;
```